# Saving and Loading lightgbm Dataset

Tags: python, load, lightgbm

I am trying to save and load lightgbm datasets using the save_binary command.

The following seems to work for the saving part:

```
import numpy as 
import lightgbm as lgb

data = lgb.Dataset(np.array([[1,2],[12,2]]))
data.save_binary('test.bin')
```

But so far, I have not been able to load the dataset back. Does anyone have an idea how I should proceed here?

Many thanks!

Comment: _How_ are you trying to load the dataset? Please provide a [mcve] and explain what exactly doesn't work and how you're expecting it to work.

Comment: Thanks for your input. Please read the question, I am not facing something not working as you suggest, but simply asking if there is an efficient way to load a lightgbm dataset saved with 'save_binary' (see the reproducible example).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Short Answer**

You can create a new Dataset from a file created with `.save_binary()` by passing a path to that file to the `data` argument of `lgb.Dataset()`.

Try this example with Python 3.7, `numpy==1.21.0`, `scikit-learn==0.24.1`, and `lightgbm==3.2.1`.

```py
import lightgbm as lgb
from numpy.testing import assert_equal
from sklearn.datasets import load_breast_cancer

X, y = load_breast_cancer(return_X_y=True)

# construct a Dataset from arrays in memory
dataset_in_mem = lgb.Dataset(
    data=X,
    label=y
)
dataset_in_mem.construct()

# save that dataset to a file
dataset_in_mem.save_binary('test.bin')

# create a new Dataset from that file
dataset_from_file = lgb.Dataset(data="test.bin")
dataset_from_file.construct()

# confirm that the Datasets are the same
print("--- X ---")
print(f"num rows: {X.shape[0]}")
print(f"num features: {X.shape[1]}")

print("--- in-memory dataset ---")
print(f"num rows: {dataset_in_mem.num_data()}")
print(f"num features: {dataset_in_mem.num_feature()}")

print("--- dataset from file ---")
print(f"num rows: {dataset_from_file.num_data()}")
print(f"num features: {dataset_from_file.num_feature()}")

# check that labels are the same
assert_equal(dataset_in_mem.label, y)
assert_equal(dataset_from_file.label, y)
```

```
--- X ---
num rows: 569
num features: 30
--- in-memory dataset ---
num rows: 569
num features: 30
--- dataset from file ---
num rows: 569
num features: 30
```

**Description**

LightGBM training requires some pre-processing of raw data, such as binning continuous features into histograms and dropping features that are unsplittable. This pre-processing is done one time, in the "construction" of a LightGBM `Dataset` object.

In the Python package (`lightgbm`), it's common to create a `Dataset` from arrays in memory. If you want to then re-use that `Dataset` many times (for example, to perform hyperparameter tuning) without needing to repeat that construction work, you can do it one time and then save the `Dataset` to a file with `.save_binary()`.

When you want to create a new `Dataset` object in memory, you can pass a filepath to the `data` argument in `lgb.Dataset()`, as shown in the sample code above.

NOTE: The `Dataset` object stored to disk will not include your raw data. So, in the sample code above, `dataset_from_file.data` is `None`. This is done for efficiency...once LightGBM has created its own "constructed" representation of the training data, it no longer needs the raw data.